# How to make bootstrap columns collapse only in equal multiples?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I have 4 equal columns in each bootstrap row. The only 3 configurations I want to allow is:

1. All 4 next to each other
2. Two above and two below
3. All in a single column

However, if I move the screen size, I sometimes get 3 columns at the top and one centered below. How can I prevent this and make the number of columns above and below equal?

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm">
      <img src="" class="img">
      </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      <img src="" class="img">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      <img src="" class="img">
     </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      <img src="" class="img">
     </div>
  </div>
```

Basically, I want to prevent this

```
1 |  2  |  3
     4
```

and only allow these:

```
1  |  2  |  3  |  4

1  |  2
3  |  4

1
2
3
4
```

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap 4 makes use of 5 different `.col` classes to denote how many columns each element should take up on various viewports:

```
.col- (extra small devices - screen width less than 576px)
.col-sm- (small devices - screen width equal to or greater than 576px)
.col-md- (medium devices - screen width equal to or greater than 768px)
.col-lg- (large devices - screen width equal to or greater than 992px)
.col-xl- (xlarge devices - screen width equal to or greater than 1200px)
```

Bearing in mind that Bootstrap has 12 columns, you simply need to divide 12 by the desired number of columns at each breakpoint to get the target `.col` that you need. For example, if you want 2 columns for medium devices, you'll divide `12` by `2` to get `6`, giving you the class `.col-md-6`.

Assuming you want 4 columns on large and extra-large devices, 2 columns on medium devices, and 1 column on small and very small devices, you'll want to make use of the following classes:

```
.col-12
.col-sm-12
.col-md-6
.col-lg-3
.col-xl-3
```

This can be seen in the following:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/100" class="img">
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/100" class="img">
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/100" class="img">
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/100" class="img">
  </div>
</div>
```

This will cause the elements to 'snap' from occupying 4 columns to only occupying 2 columns as you drag the viewport to be narrower.

PS: Also note that you have two rogue `</div>` in your example, which will mess up the display if these exist in your actual code.

Comment: Thanks! The rogue divs were because of incorrect copying and pasting. Fixed it now for future visitors to this question. I have used bootstrap for a few years now but have never seen the grid used like that. I appreciate the help!